# doxygen: not found

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I came across with problems when installing openni_kinect following this website:http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect,

- Creating Doxygen...
  sh: 1: doxygen: not found
  failed to execute: doxygen Doxyfile > /home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/drivers/openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/Output/EngineDoxy.txt
  Creating Documentation Failed!
  make[1]: *** [installed] Error 1
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/drivers/openni'
  make: *** [openni_lib] Error 2

How to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39839/doxygen:-not-found/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install doxygen from Ubuntu Software Center, then the problem can be fixed:)

---

Originally posted by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) with karma: 286 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3